# How start a WSO2 APIM 4.1.0 using docker-compose.yaml and PostgreSQL as datasource

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, docker-compose, wso2-api-manager

Error deploying WSO2 with postgresql.
I don't find any in https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-databases/changing-default-databases/changing-to-postgresql/

**I need to use PostgreSQL as datasource to WSO2 APIM 4.1.0. When I try start WSO2 using docker container, i'm receiving this log error:**

```
    [2022-08-07 08:46:15,496] ERROR - Activator Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
wso2_apim      | org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:286) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:102) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
wso2_apim      | Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:325) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:136) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        ... 22 more
wso2_apim      | Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:404) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:231) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:136) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        ... 22 more
wso2_apim      | Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
wso2_apim      |        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:358) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:231) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:136) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        ... 22 more
wso2_apim      | Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: DB error occurred while persisting domain : PRIMARY & tenant id : -1234
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:931) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.persistDomain(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:9083) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:320) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:262) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.java:129) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:358) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:231) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:136) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        ... 22 more
wso2_apim      | Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
wso2_apim      |        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
wso2_apim      |        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
wso2_apim      |        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
wso2_apim      |        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
wso2_apim      |        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
wso2_apim      |        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:347) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:228) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:769) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:697) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:134) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil.getDBConnection(DatabaseUtil.java:1067) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:911) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.persistDomain(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:9083) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:320) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:262) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.java:129) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:358) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:231) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:136) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        ... 22 more
wso2_apim      | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
wso2_apim      |        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
wso2_apim      |        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
wso2_apim      |        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
wso2_apim      |        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
wso2_apim      |        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
wso2_apim      |        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
wso2_apim      |        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
wso2_apim      |        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
wso2_apim      |        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:347) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:228) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:769) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:697) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:134) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil.getDBConnection(DatabaseUtil.java:1067) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:911) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.persistDomain(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:9083) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:320) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:262) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.java:129) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:358) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:231) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:136) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
wso2_apim      |        ... 22 more
```

---

> - I tried using MySQL and worked 100% but using PostgreSQL simply don't work.
> - I can connect with Postgres using DBeaver;
> - The JDBC driver is working;
>
> I tried change Postgres version to 9.6, 10, 14, 14.4; I tried change
> JDBC driver version... I tried change pg_hba.conf; I tried change
> Postgres database name, password;

**My deployment.toml:**

```
[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"

#POSTGRES
[database.shared_db]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
[database.shared_db.pool_options]
maxActive = 10000
maxWait = 10000000
validationInterval = 1000000

[database.apim_db]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
[database.apim_db.pool_options]
maxActive = 10000
maxWait = 10000000
validationInterval = 1000000
```

The expected result is start WSO2 APIM 4.1.0 using PostgreSQL as datasource without errors.

Comment: Are you running postgresql as a service within the docker-compose.yml?

Comment: Yes, i'm using the same docker-compose.yml to postgres and wso2 apim.
I'm using depends_on: postgres_service on apim_service

Comment: Can you connect to the postres db directly using command line or another tool like dbeaver?

Comment: Yes, I can connect directly and using DBeaver too. User and password are ok.

Answer (score 0):

By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

Instead of using `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres` as the DB url, try using the service name that you have given for the postgre instance.

For eg: If you have given `db` as the service name in the docker-compose.yaml, then the DB url would be `jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgres`

[1] - https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: It worked very well...
Now I have other issue but it's not same problem. 

Thanks!